# one Macro replace issue

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define AMP_Assert( expr ) if( !(expr) ) { \
    printf("** Assertion failed: \"" #expr "\" at %s:%d %s()\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);\
    }

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int a = 1;
    AMP_Assert(a % 8 == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

The below warning will happen in gcc and msvc

```
macrotest.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
macrotest.cpp:4:95: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘ ’ in format [-Wformat=]
```

How to get rid of this warning? Let ‘%’ in macro replace to be replaced correctly.

Comment: `printf("Assertion failed: %s at ...", #expr, ...)`

Comment: Thanks, it is fine for me.